# Using external .kv file vs doing things internally?

Tags: python, kivy

I have noticed that most examples I foind online don't have an external `.kv` file. They define all the instances internally. However they also say that having an external `.kv` file is a good practice. Which is better to do? If having external `.kv`files are better, then how am I supposed to use the code which uses internal code and turn it into external `.kv` files?
For example, doing this ->

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class TutorialApp(App):
    def build(self):
        b = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        t = TextInput(font_size=150,
                      size_hint_y=None,
                      height=200,
                      text='default')

        f = FloatLayout()
        s = Scatter()
        l = Label(text='default',
                  font_size=150)

        t.bind(text=l.setter('text'))

        f.add_widget(s)
        s.add_widget(l)

        b.add_widget(t)
        b.add_widget(f)
        return b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TutorialApp().run()
```

Instead of-

```
<ScatterTextWidget>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    TextInput:
        id: my_textinput
        font_size: 150
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 200
        text: 'default'
    FloatLayout:
        Scatter:
            Label:
                text: my_textinput.text
                font_size: 150
```

Comment: I like to avoid the .kv language stuff entirely when I can... when I have to use it i like to use Builder.build_string right before i create the python code for the class .... that way it is nicely coupled ... just my 2c, this question will probably get closed since its not really appropriate for stack overflow

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use kivy lang? It was made for a purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Internal" usage of kv is through [`Builder`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.builder.html) class, which allows you even to load external file. Those examples are worded in a `Builder.load_string(...)` way because it's way simpler to have a small example in one place in one file.

How to convert it to the external one? Simple, copy&paste the string from `Builder.load_string()` into a separate `.kv` file with a name of your class that inherits from App(your main class with `build()`) and that's it. It'll load the same thing from the external file.

Why it's better or worse? Isn't any of that actually. It's like comparing "java" and python style i.e. either putting everything out of your file and having basically this construction a'la java, where the main file contains this:

```
class This(something):
    SpecialClass.doThis()
    AnotherClass.doThat()
```

and other classes(or different things) are in separate files. Or this construction:

```
class Special(...):
    ...

class Another(...):
    ...

class This(something):
    Special.do_this()
    Another.do_that()
```

Both of them are useful and you'll find yourself working with a mix between them. It's about transparency and clearness of your code, but maybe you don't want to have a hundred of files... or a 2MB `main.py`, pretty much compromise of how do you decide to code.

**Edit:**
The python vs kv is a funny "fight", but except a `for`(and `while`?) loop you can pretty much do everything necessary inside kv in such an easy way! Kv is here to make writing easier e.g. remove too much stuff like `add_widget()` or basically making an empty class just to rename a widget or to change its size for using it in one place.

With python in a 500line file without kv you won't do that much as with 100 extra lines in kv. The documentation has important parts in python and maybe it's even targeted for users who can't/don't want to use kv. Also this and all examples highly depend on the author of an example and that particular part of the docs.

Which returns me back to the java vs python style of coding I mentioned before. It's pointless to do complicated stuff just because you think it'll feel/look better if you can do it cleaner and more readable i.e. don't just go *one* way if you have a tool that increase your speed of coding exponentially. Find the middle way.

Comment: I am not talking about the `Builder.load_string()` function. Here I am comparing **the KV Language** and standard Python for defining UI elements through Kivy. Edit- I edited the question with example.

Comment: I have a doubt. Will not ```Builder.load_string()``` faster than ```Builder.load_file()```, given that the latter will need to perform the additional step of opening and closing the file ?